# JavaFX init() method resetting field to null

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating a small program in JavaFX, and have a Button which I need to assign an EventHandler. I create and assign this button within my View's (the class that extends Application) init() method.

```
Button ok = new Button("   OK   ");
ok.setOnAction(this.eventHandler);
```

Ideally I'd like to pass this eventHandler in when I construct the View object, but I've had some difficulties doing that, so I resolved myself to just using a simple setter.

```
public void setEventHandler(EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler) {
 this.eventHandler = eventHandler;
}
```

To kick everything off, I run a few lines of code within my Controller class's main method:

```
View v = new View();
v.setEventHandler(new HandleOk(v));
javafx.application.Application.launch(View.class);
```

Where HandleOk is the EventHandler. It needs a reference to my view class so it can query the state of some of its fields, and thus is constructed with a View. Running this code and clicking on the JavaFX button leads to a null pointer exception.

I then set up three `System.out.format("Event handler is null: %b\n", v.eventHandler == null);`, one in my Controller's main method, one at the top of my View's init() method (a method inherited from JavaFX Application), and within the button's setOnAction method. Thus the following:

```
public class Controller {
  //~~ other stuff ~~
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    View v = new View();
    v.setEventHandler(new HandleOk(v));
    System.out.format("Event handler is null: %b\n", v.eventHandler == null);
    javafx.application.Application.launch(View.class);
  }
 //~~ other stuff ~~
}

public class View extends Application {
  EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler;

  public void setEventHandler(EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler) {
    System.out.println("Event Handler set");
    this.eventHandler = eventHandler;
  }

  @Override
  public void init() {
    System.out.format("Event Handler in init() is null: %b\n", eventHandler == null);
  //  ~~ other stuff ~~
    Button ok = new Button("   OK   ");
    ok.setOnAction((ActionEvent) -> {
      System.out.format("Event Handler in button is null: %b", this.eventHandler == null));
      if (!(this.eventHandler == null) {
        this.eventHandler.handle(ActionEvent);
      }
    });
 //   ~~ other stuff ~~
  }
```

Running this and clicking on the button in my javaFX application leads to the following being printed to the console:

```
Event Handler set
Event Handler is null: false
Event Handler in init() is null: true
Event Handler in button is null: true
```

Interestingly enough, adding the following line to my init() method removes the null pointer exception and my application works.

```
public void init() {
  eventHandler = new Controller.HandleOk(this);
 // ~~  other stuff ~~
}
```

Ideally I'd like my Controller to pass in the HandleOk to my View, and not my View to have to grab the HandleOk from my Controller. I can only conclude that when JavaFX loads a class that extends application, it resets whatever fields have been initialized, leading to a situation where you can only initialize fields within the init() method. How can I pass in the HandleOk to the View from an external source?

Comment: Doesn't "javafx.application.Application.launch(View.class);" create its own instance of View? This would mean anything you did before this would be pointless, as the instance which is getting displayed is not the instance you created

Comment: The documentation confirms your answer, so now I know why the field seemingly is reset. Launch is a void method and doesn't return a reference to the instance, however, so I'm still lost on how to pass in the HandleOk externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
Application.launch(View.class)
```

is creating a new instance of View where it has null value for event handler by default, and also is different from the View class you created yourself. Also if you noticed the init() method of View class is invoked only once. This was invoked by Application.launch method.

I suggest to split View and Application logic to different classes. I.e. don't extend view from `Application`, create another class MainApp that extends  Application.

Comment: Can you elaborate on splitting up the View and Application logic? My thought was that my View has a button, that when clicked would message my Controller. From there my Controller talks to my Model to do the job. How would this flow look different with splitting up my View and Application?

Comment: Basically my controller should be the class that extends Application, since it is the entry point for my program. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you **set** the field?

```
public void setEventHandler(EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler) {
    System.out.println("Event Handler set");
    this.eventHandler = eventHandler; // missing?   
}
```